# RxJava infinite stream best practice

Tags: android, rx-java

In android app i have this case:

Listen to my editText with observable:

```
WidgetObservable.text(myEditText, false)
    .map { it.text().toString() }
    .debounce(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
```

Then i need to send network request with string emitted by observable:

```
    .flatMap { networkObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) }
```

My question is: what is the best possible way to write infinite stream of these network results. 
Errors handled by UI.

Unsubscription done with AppObservable.bindActivity() wrapper

I ended up attaching materialize() operator to network observable, and then handling it like:

```
    .subscribe{
          when (it.getKind()) {
            Kind.OnNext  -> text.setText(it.getValue())
            Kind.OnError -> text.setText(it.getThrowable().getMessage())
          }
    }
```

Do you know better way, or its just fine?
At least it works.

P.S. another useful case will be Refresh button clicks flatMap'ed to network calls

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onErrorResumeNext` to recovery your Observable from a failure. E.g.,

```
WidgetObservable.text(myEditText, false)
    .map { it.text().toString() }
    .debounce(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap {
          networkObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                           .onErrorResumeNext(t -> t.getMessage())
    }
```

Comment: It means i need some wrapper object contained normal and error state, that will be emitted after flatMap transformation?
In terms of readability and overhead seems my solution better. No?

Comment: You can also use `onErrorResumeNext` in the outer Observable instead of in the flatMap.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand this approach. 
If anyone knows another ones, post new answers please!

Comment: Sorry that I just realized that using `onErrorResumeNext` in the outer Observable is wrong. Because the upstream only emits one `onError` event and ignores the further ones.

Comment: Could you move the outer operations into the inner flatMap?